# SharedAssemblyInfo.cs & VB Projects

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have been using a SharedAssemblyInfo.cs file as a linked file in my C# projects.
With the introduction of some VB.net projects into the solution I have done the same with those.
Although it does not give a compiler error, it does not 'add' the values from the linked SharedAssemblyInfo.cs file into the compiled assembly.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the VB.Net compiler will only compile files with a .vb extension.  If you link a .cs file into the project it will be ignored by the IDE.

Also the structure of the .cs file will not be compilable by the .VB compiler since it's C# code.  You'll need to create a SharedAssemblyInfo.vb file for all of your VB.Net projects and link that file in instead.